# How to access the openstack vm instance from external network from VM

Tags: sockets, networking, cloud, openstack

I have the following scenario, I have two file client and server file which is containerised using docker containers. Client container is residing on a VM using a virtual box (network set using NAT and host-only adapter) and server container is residing on OpenStack VM.
The IP address of the server is 192.168.160.39 and the VM machine IP address is enp0s8:192.168.56.108.
I am running the docker container client as

```
docker run --rm -it -p 192.168.56.108:5555:5555 client bash
```

and running server docker container as

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5555:5555 server bash
```

Client.py

```
context = zmq.Context()
#Socket to talk to server
socket = context.socket( zmq.REQ )
socket.connect( "tcp://192.168.160.39:5555" )
name = "Max"
while True:
  message = input( "Message: " )
  socket.send_pyobj( {1: [name, message]} )
```

Server.py

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:5555")
while True:
   #Wait for next request from client
   message = socket.recv_pyobj()
   print("%s: %s" % (message.get(1)[0], message.get(1)[1]))
```

I am able to access OpenStack VM by ssh from my VM using ssh -J proxy-server OpenStack VM.
for instance
ssh -J 4020343@hpdc.xxx.xx ubuntu@192.168.160.39

My server is unable to retrieve the data from the client. Thanks, help is highly appreciated helping me in sorting out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an openstack  instance id, you can find the  right sec. group with:

example:

```
openstack server show  284c39d2-79af-485d-8f63-9ac3620cf119 | grep security_groups
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the security groups? The port in which your server is listening (5555) should be opened in the VM that is in OpenStack.

Comment: Thanks for point out this @Carlos. I figured out that the network setting set is to private.